# How to download the iso file of ubuntu in command line?

Tags: system-installation, putty

I need to install the VirtualBox in the company's server by the client, PuTTY. Then install the ubuntu 14.04 in the VirtualBox. Right now I have find the methods of installing the VirtualBox in the server. However, I cannot download the iso file in the way of command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`wget "http://web address for direct download of the iso"`

Example : `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: Thx very much. It works!!!

Comment: @user272261: You may mark the answer as accepted(click on the tick besides the answer) since it has solved your problem.

Comment: yes, but how do I install this after downloading? can I install the upgrade from the command line?

Comment: I can I only burn the .iso to disc and then book from there

Answer (score 0):

As I find this question useful, I leave my answer here in case some newbies (like me) meet this problem.

Ubuntu 22.04 iso download:

wget "https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"

Ubuntu 22.04 Server iso download:

wget "https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso"

Ubuntu 20.04 iso download:

wget "https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso"

Ubuntu 20.04 Server iso download:

wget "https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.5-live-server-amd64.iso"